# USB tool to make Windows 8 bootable from a USB flash drive?

Tags: windows-8, usb

For Windows 7, Microsoft released the "Microsoft Store - Windows 7 USB/DVD Download tool". What is the equivalent to this for Windows 8.0 and 8.1? Is there some third-party software I can use to make it bootable from a USB flash drive?

I have prepared the ISO file for 8.1 but I'm not sure what tool to use. I would normally have used ImgBurn and burned that ISO to a blank DVD disc. But this is a laptop and it has no ODD.

Comment: [How To Install Windows 8 or 8.1 From a USB Device](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows-8/a/install-windows-8-usb.htm) ?  Is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: Yes and no. I was on that same page before I posted her. I have tried the Microsoft USB tool for Windows 7 and it didn't work. I am looking for an alternative tool. What other tool is there?

Comment: Didn't Microsoft create a new tool for Windows 8?

Comment: Nope, and the current tool works with windows 8 as well.

Comment: Try Rufus - http://www.filehorse.com/download-rufus/

Answer (score 3):

First time I've seen someone refer to a USB drive/flash drive/thumb drive as a UFD - The USB download tool you mentioned will work for windows 8 (and presumably for 8.1, which isn't generally offered as an ISO) with the same constraints as windows 7 (you can't create a x64 boot disk on a x86 system in my experience).

Answer (score 2):

Actually you don't require any software to make USB bootable for Windows 7, 8, 8.1 . You have to just extract the OS's ISO file to your USB (Do not extract it to any subfolder). Make that USB volume `Active` in `Disk Management`. To do this, follow below steps.

1. Run `diskmgmt.msc`. (Run short-cut: <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>)
2. Right click on the USB in the volume list
3. Click `Mark Partition as Active`

Make sure in your BIOS, it's set to boot from USB.